# Import data from a large CSV (or stream of data) to Neo4j efficiently in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, neo4j, backgroundworker

I am new to background processes, so feel free to point me out if I am making wrong assumptions.

I am trying to write a script that imports import data into a Neo4j db from a large CSV file (consider it as a stream of data, endless). The csv file only contains two column - user_a_id and user_b_id, which maps the directed relations. A few things to consider:

1. data might have duplicates
2. the same user can map to multiple other users and is not guaranteed that when it will show up again.

My current solution: I am using sidekiq and have one worker to read the file in batches and dispatch workers to create edges in the database.

Problems that I am having:

1. Since the I am receiving a stream of data, I cannot pre-sort the file and assign job that build relation for one user.
2. Since jobs are performed asynchronously, if two workers are working on relation of the same node, I will get a write lock from Neo4j.
3. Let's say I get around with the write lock, if two workers are working on records that are duplicated, I will build duplicated edges.

Possible solution: Build a synchronous queue and have only one worker to perform writing (Seems neither sidekiq or resque has the option). And this could be pretty slow since only one thread is working on the job.

Or, I can write my own implementation, which create one worker to build multiple queues of jobs based on user_id (one unique id per queue), and use redis to store them. Then assign one worker per queue to write to database. Set a maximum number of queues so I wouldn't run out of memory, and delete the queue once it exhausts all the jobs (rebuild it if I see the same user_id in the future). - This doesn't sound trivial though, so I would prefer using an existing library before diving into this.

My question is — is there a existing gem that I can use? What is a good practice of handling this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a number of options ;)

If your data really is in a file and not as a stream, I would definitely recommend checking out the [neo4j-import](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html) command which comes with Neo4j.  It allows you to import CSV data at speeds on the order of 1 million rows per second.  Two caveats: You may need to modify your file format a bit, and you would need to be generating a fresh database (it doesn't import new data into an existing database)

I would also be familiar with the [`LOAD CSV`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html) command.  This takes a CSV in any format and lets you write some Cypher commands to transform and import the data.  It's not as fast as `neo4j-import`, but it's pretty fast and it can stream a CSV file from disk or a URL.

Since you're using Ruby, I would also suggest checking out [neo4apis](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4apis).  This is a gem that I wrote to make it easier to batch import data so that you're not making a single request for every entry in your file.  It allows you to define a class in a sort of DSL with importers.  These importers can take any sort of Ruby object and, given that Ruby object, will define what should be imported using `add_node` and `add_relationship` methods.  Under the covers this generates Cypher queries which are buffered and executed in batches so that you don't have lots of round trips to Neo4j.

I would investigate all of those things first before thinking about doing things asynchronously.  If you really do have a never ending set of data coming in, however.  The [`MERGE`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html) clause should help you with any race conditions or locks.  It allows you to create objects and relationships if they don't already exist.  It's basically a `find_or_create`, but at a database level.  If you use `LOAD CSV` you'll probably want merge as well, and `neo4apis` uses `MERGE` under the covers.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Brian for all the options! Let me take a look into them and will get back to you. You mentioned neo4j-import. Since it doesn't import into an existing database, it's not a valid option for my situation since I already have the database in place, and I need to port the relation part into it. But good to know though!

Comment: Cool, happy to help!  If you need any real-time help I'm one of the maintainers of the Neo4j.rb project and we hang out on Gitter: https://gitter.im/neo4jrb/neo4j