# Import a large (7 million rows) csv file into Neo4j faster

Tags: csv, neo4j

this is my first question in stackoverflow.

I'd like to import a 7 million rows file in Neo4j database.

Each row has information of a node, a time value (which are already in database).
For each row, I would need to find an existing node, and an existing time value in the database, then create a relationship between them, and add values in it accordingly.

I'd like some advise to improve import speed. The schema is:

```
ON :Day(value)        ONLINE  
ON :Month(value)      ONLINE  
ON :SEGMENT(LinkName) ONLINE  
ON :Timeperiod(value) ONLINE  
ON :Year(value)       ONLINE
```

It takes me 24 hours for import around 2 million rows. (1/3 of it) I would expect to import 50 similar files thus I think I would need better code to increase speed.
The allocated memory is 1GB (default setting) and the harddisk is SSD.

Thanks so much!

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///../../Python/MAR15.csv" AS row WITH row
WHERE row.LinkRef IS NOT NULL
WITH row, toInt(SUBSTRING(row.Date, 0, 4)) AS y
MATCH (year:Year {value: y})
WITH row, year, toInt(SUBSTRING(row.Date, 5, 2)) AS m
MATCH (year)-[:CONTAINS]->(month:Month {value: m})
WITH row, month, toInt(SUBSTRING(row.Date, 8, 2)) AS d
MATCH (month)-[:CONTAINS]->(day:Day {value: d})
WITH row, day, toInt(row.TimePeriod) AS t
MATCH (day)-[:CONTAINS]->(timeperiod:Timeperiod {value: t}) 
##96 period per day, each period is 15 minutes
WITH row, timeperiod
MATCH(segment:SEGMENT {LinkRef: row.LinkRef})


CREATE (segment)-[trafficdata:TrafficData {
    AverageJT: row.AverageJT,
    AverageSpeed: row.AverageSpeed,
    Flow: row.Flow,
    DataQuality: row.DataQuality
    }]->(timeperiod)
SET segment.LinkLength = row.LinkLength;
```

Comment: what have you looked at? If you have seen these then please add them to your question? maybe interesting? http://jexp.de/blog/2013/05/on-importing-data-in-neo4j-blog-series/  Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487313/import-data-from-a-large-csv-or-stream-of-data-to-neo4j-efficiently-in-ruby.  Also: - guessing: https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiS2tn3nYrNAhXqIsAKHfsvD8QQtwIISDAH&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DdCM7fRb49Ts&usg=AFQjCNHj37KJGDXPx9GIeLQqh5C2kCT_Ow&sig2=UXG6yAMBF94jryPSw1lFyA&bvm=bv.123664746,d.ZGg

Comment: That is about 23 records per second?  Is interesting (disappointing)?  I hope that someone can assist with improving that? I would hope for between 1 to 2 orders of magnitude speed up?

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your suggestion. For the video in the 2nd link. I have learnt to create constraint on unique LinkRef. It IS much faster now.

        CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (segment:SEGMENT) 
        ASSERT segment.LinkRef IS UNIQUE

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Ryan, I improved the query speed by this code:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (segment:SEGMENT) ASSERT segment.LinkRef IS UNIQUE
```

Since each SEGMENT has a unique identifier (LinkRef), the system is able to perform the MATCH checking much faster.
The system is able handle more than 10,000 inputs per minute after adding this constraint.